# Postgresql 10 Logical replication MultiMaster

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

Is it possible use Postgresql 10 logical replication as multimaster? I'm trying install two linux ubuntu server with postgresql 10, but all the sample I have found implement the replication as master to slave and I need to take the replication allowing change the data in the two databases (Publication and Subscriber).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but it probably won't work well. The logical replication in postgres 10 doesn't have conflict resolution features, so it'll fall over quite easily if you write (say) a row with the same primary key to each DB.

It should work well for disjoint sets where no conflicts are possible.

If you need conflict handling you can use BDR for now or another multimaster replication solution.